# Not able to configure on IIS client certificate

Tags: c#, .net, azure, iis-10

I have a very weird situation:

We have migrated the virtual machine A from Hyper-V to Azure (VM B).

Our surprise is that one web service deployed in IIS is giving 403. After some investigation we noticed that if on IIS we check the options 'Accept' or 'Require' then 403 is raised.
Of course the client (windows service done in C#) didnt change and its sending the certificate in the request (using c# HttpClient) as always.

[image: Reference 1]

The error is:

[image: Ref: Error SS]

VM A and B are exactly the same, so I can not find what its happening.

Everything we read on internet about this error didnt fix it, so any help would be very appreciated.

We have IIS 10 over Windows Server 2016 (DataCenter).

Best regards.

I expect that IIS doesnt refuse requests when the SSL client certificate is either accepted or required.

Comment: That HTTP 403 error doesn't look like a Client Certificate issue. Is your AppPool Identity and NTFS permissions set correctly? Have you enabled Failed Request tracing and looked at the logs?

Comment: This should be rather asked on serverfault as this is not a programming problem

Comment: Read IIS log files and know which substatus code you hit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code From there you might know what's wrong. Most likely the IIS machine doesn't trust the client certificates as you missed the steps to configure the CAs (and you should see 403.16 recorded in log files).

Comment: Try using FRT to view details about the 403 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis. You can get better answers If you provide more details about the error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually using HTTPS in your URL? The "Require" option prevents you from using HTTP. When a request comes via a non-SSL connection, it returns a 403. When a client attempts to access a resource that requires a client certificate, the server verifies the validity of the client certificate. If the client certificate is invalid or not provided, the access request will be denied.

When you want to enable two-way ssl authentication, you need to select the "Require" option. This means that the client also needs to send its certificate, which will be authenticated by the server.

If you want to force https whenever someone visits your site, never use "Require" but instead use an HTTP to HTTPS redirect.